# I'm returning a promise and receive : Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js, callback

```
exports.admin= function(req, res, next){

    if(!req.user)
    {
        var err = new Error ('No Valid User');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
    else if(!req.user.admin)
    {
        var err = new Error ('You must be an administrator!');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('IN'); // <---- I hit this
        return next();
    }     
}
```

So I have this function and it is called here:

```
routerA.route('/').post( (req,res,next)=> {

     authenticate.admin(req, res, next)
    .then(()=>{ // <-----here on this line I receive this exception
        console.log('AAA')
        Dishes.create(req.body)
        .then((dish)=>{
            console.log('Dish Created: ', dish);

            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            res.json(dish);
        },  (err)=>next(err))
        .catch((err)=>next(err));
    });  

})
```

I don't get it I return the promise from admin, why I receive this exception Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

Comment: How do we know you are returning a promise when you haven't shown what the next middleware is? Does `next` return a promise?

Comment: `next` is not a promise in express, you probably want to call `admin` as middleware. `routerA.route('/').post(authenticate.admin, (req,res,next)=> {})`

Comment: @Matt I swear I tried to chain it first and error was happening. Sorry for the noob question. I just start it node.js. Write it as answer I will mark it as correct one. Now is working

Comment: @mybirthname All good, happens to everyone :)  Take a look at [Koa](http://koajs.com/) if you want express but with promises. Error handling for promise code becomes easier at least.

Comment: @Matt thanks I will check it later, good luck and thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` is not a promise in [express](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express). It's a callback to tell express to move onto the next middleware, whatever that may be.

Call `authenticate.admin` as [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). Then the call to `next()` will allow express to move onto your request handler.

```
routerA.route('/').post(authenticate.admin, (req,res,next)=> {
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

But you are returning `next()` which doesn't return a promise. It returns `undefined`.